# Подключение нескольких файлов в проекте. C++

Tags: c++

У меня есть 3 файла.

integer_stack.h

```
 #ifndef _INTEGER_STACK_HPP_
    #define _INTEGER_STACK_HPP_

#include <iostream>

struct IntegerStack;

IntegerStack * IntegerStackCreate();

IntegerStack * IntegerStackCreate(int _fixedSize);
```

integer_stack_array_impl.cpp

```
#include <cassert>
#include "integer_stack.h"

struct IntegerStack
{
    int * m_pData;
    int * m_pTop;
    int m_Size;
};


IntegerStack * IntegerStackCreate(int _fixedSize)
{
    IntegerStack * pStack = new IntegerStack;

    pStack->m_pData = new int[_fixedSize];
    pStack->m_pTop = pStack->m_pData;
    pStack->m_Size = _fixedSize;

    return pStack;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "integer_stack.h"

using namespace std;

void main() {
    IntegerStack someStack;
    system("pause");
}
```

При попытке создания объекта для структуры, которая определена в заголовочном файле и реализована в integer_stack_array_impl.cpp, получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Error   1   error C2079: 'sd' uses undefined struct 'IntegerStack'
```

То есть доступа к этой структуре из main.cpp у меня нету. Как правильно подключить и соединить эти файлы между собой? Ибо другие способы вызывают ошибку 
вроде этой:

```
error LNK2005: "void __cdecl IntegerStackClear(struct IntegerStack &)" (?IntegerStackClear@@YAXAAUIntegerStack@@@Z) already defined in integer_stack_array_impl.obj
```

Comment: То там у вас за LNK2005 и почему - из вашего описания не ясно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите явно определять объекты типа `IntegerStack`, то определение класса `IntegerStack` вам придется поместить в заголовочный файл, т.е. в ваш `integer_stack.h`, тем самым выставив напоказ всему свету его содержимое.

Однако, судя по функциям, присутствующим в `integer_stack.h`, тип `IntegerStack` задуман именно как "непрозрачный" класс (opaque class), то есть класс со скрытой реализацией. В этом случае вы не должны явно определять объекты этого типа. С чего это вдруг вы пытаетесь это делать? Объявлять вам разрешается только *указатели* на этот тип, а создавать сами объекты будет в своих недрах функция `IntegerStackCreate()` и ей подобные

```
IntegerStack *someStack = IntegerStackCreate();
// И т.д.
```

И работать с созданным таким образом объектом вы сможете только через интерфейсные функции, предоставляемые `integer_stack.h`.

Другими словами, вам надо сначала определиться, что именно вы пытаетесь сделать. Если вам нужна возможность явно напрямую определять объекты

```
IntegerStack someStack;
```

то тогда забудьте о методах сокрытия реализации, которые использованы в вашем `integer_stack.h`. Если же вы хотите скрыть реализацию `IntegerStack` через технику opaque class, то тогда забудьте о возможности делать такие определения объектов.

Либо одно, либо другое<sup>1</sup>.

P.S. `int main()`, а не `void main()`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Существуют методы сокрытия реализации, которые сочетают преимущества обоих вариантов (в стиле того, как на основе `std::aligned_storage` обычно реализуется `std::optional` и `std::variant`), но это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: а в чём существенная разница между `int main()` и `void main()` если они оба работают безо всяких проблем ? тоесть во втором случае ОС просто не может определить успешно или безуспешно завершилась программа  (так как программа не возвращает код ошибки) ??

Comment: в том, что первый вариант - по стандарту (3.6.1 - main должна возвращать int), а второй - конкретная реализация в компиляторе. И он уж должен следовать стандарту и возвращать 0, где нужно.